# cakephp how to setting up ACL permission

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.x version.

I have done with Simple Acl controlled Application http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html

But i am getting stuck in Simple Acl controlled Application - part 2 http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/part-two.html

I have download AclExtras plugin and run `./Console/cake AclExtras.AclExtras aco_sync` command.

And my command line output is:

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\SIMPLE_ACL_APP\app>cake acl create aco root controllers


Welcome to CakePHP v2.6.1 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: D:\xampp\htdocs\SIMPLE_ACL_APP\app\
---------------------------------------------------------------
New Aco 'controllers' created.



D:\xampp\htdocs\SIMPLE_ACL_APP\app>cake AclExtras.AclExtras aco_sync


Welcome to CakePHP v2.6.1 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: D:\xampp\htdocs\SIMPLE_ACL_APP\app\
---------------------------------------------------------------
Created Aco node: controllers/Groups
Created Aco node: controllers/Groups/index
Created Aco node: controllers/Groups/view
Created Aco node: controllers/Groups/add
Created Aco node: controllers/Groups/edit
Created Aco node: controllers/Groups/delete
Created Aco node: controllers/Pages
Created Aco node: controllers/Pages/display
Created Aco node: controllers/Posts
Created Aco node: controllers/Posts/index
Created Aco node: controllers/Posts/view
Created Aco node: controllers/Posts/add
Created Aco node: controllers/Posts/edit
Created Aco node: controllers/Posts/delete
Created Aco node: controllers/Users
Created Aco node: controllers/Users/initDB
Created Aco node: controllers/Users/login
Created Aco node: controllers/Users/logout
Created Aco node: controllers/Users/index
Created Aco node: controllers/Users/view
Created Aco node: controllers/Users/add
Created Aco node: controllers/Users/edit
Created Aco node: controllers/Users/delete
Created Aco node: controllers/Widgets
Created Aco node: controllers/Widgets/index
Created Aco node: controllers/Widgets/view
Created Aco node: controllers/Widgets/add
Created Aco node: controllers/Widgets/edit
Created Aco node: controllers/Widgets/delete
Created Aco node: controllers/AclExtras
Aco Update Complete
```

I have tring to seeing permissions but cant do the **Setting up permissions** .

[See document](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/part-two.html#setting-up-permissions). `cake acl` command not work for me.

Please help me out.

Comment: I don't actually see a question here but I'll try... are you asking how to use cake acl? If so have you tried ./Console/cake acl ?

Answer (score 0):

From your htdocs/app folder run the following command (for example):

```
Console/cake acl grant NameOfYourUserGroup controllers
```

Using the -h option after 'grant' explains this. 
If you see "Persmission was not granted" error then you may have your arguments the wrong way around or either the ARO or ACO referenced does not exist.